# Calculate sum of auto filled input using javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have three input fields with auto filled / auto calculated values. The values are derived from other input fields.

```
total_p1 = sum of input1 and input2  ||| 
total_p2 = sum of input3 and input4
total = total_p1 + total_p2
```

I need to add the values of `total_p1` and `total_p2`. Problem is it won't calculate unless I manually add or change the value of either input boxes. Hoping for an effective solution for auto fill. Thanks!

EDIT:

code for total_p1:

```
$('#input2').keyup(function(){
    var input1;
    var input2;

    input1 = parseFloat($('#input1').val());
    input2=  parseFloat($('#input2').val());

    var result = (input1 + input2);
    $("#total_p1").val(result);  
});
```

code for total_p2:

```
$('#input4').keyup(function(){
    var input3;
    var input4;

    input3 = parseFloat($('#input3').val());
    input4=  parseFloat($('#input4').val());

    var result = (input3 + input4);
    $("#total_p2").val(result);  
});
```

Code for total:

total:

code for total_p1:

```
$('#total_p2').keyup(function(){
    var total_p1;
    var total_p2;

    total_p1= parseFloat($('#total_p1').val());
    total_p2=  parseFloat($('#total_p2').val());

    var result = (total_p+ total_p2);
    $("#total").val(result);  
});
```

Comment: Please share your code first!!!

Comment: document.querySelector('#input2').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { 'bubbles': true }));

Comment: You are using keyup event listeners, so if you are changing a value programmatically, no event is triggered. You can use the change event instead and manually trigger that event when changing programmatically. Kinda like this: https://fiddle.jshell.net/9u74aLvp/

Comment: Change event only fires when the input field loses focus. If that's not good enough, the `input` event fires immediately when the field has changed by typing or pasting. No matter what event you use, you need to trigger it manually for programmatic changes to the source fields, as Tom says.

Answer (score 0):

Add class `input-fields-to-sum` to your source input fields, then:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   calculateTotals();

    $(".input-fields-to-sum").on('input', function() {
        calculateTotals();
    });
});

function calculateTotals() {
   // walk on input fields with class, calculate sum and put it in total field
   // input can contain invalid numbers, handle errors when parsing
}

function parseNumber(str, defaultValue) {
    if (str !== undefined && str.length) {
        var parsed = parseFloat(str.replace(',','.').replace(/\s/g,'').replace(/\&nbsp\;/g,''));
        if (isNaN(parsed)) return defaultValue;
        return parsed;
    }
    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Here's what I did that somehow worked. I'm new to javascript so I'm not really sure if I'm on the right track.

`$(document).ready(function() {
   calculateTotals();

    $(".input-fields-to-sum").on('input', function() {
        calculateTotals();
    });
});

function calculateTotals() {

      $('#total_p2').keyup(function(){

        var total_p1;
        var total_p2;

    total_p1= parseFloat($('#total_p1').val());
    total_p2=  parseFloat($('#total_p2').val());

    var result = (total_p+ total_p2);
   $("#total").val(result);
   });
}`

Comment: I think so. The only thing missing is that you need to initialize the total field in document.ready after page load. After that, the event handler will handle the calculation.

Comment: parseFloat can return NaN if the number is invalid (e.g. only a minus sign), you need to handle that.

Comment: That's what I'm working on right now. It's showing NaN.

Comment: Added a number parsing function to my answer. It handles both comma and dot as decimal point which might not be suitable for you.